# Unable to read Data Array. Getting: Uncaught Error: Unknown type of column header: 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am fetching data table from google sheet, but Pie chart is unable to read the Array. I am getting below error on console.

> Uncaught Error: Unknown type of column header: 1

I am using below script to get the data from Google Spreadsheet.

Code.gs:

```js
function vodPiechart() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  const sw = ss.getSheetByName("Pie_Chart_Data");
  var data = sw.getRange (1,1,3, 2).getValues();
  return data
}
```

HTML Script ([from Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData);
      function getData(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).vodPiechart();
      }
      function drawChart(dataReturened) {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataReturened);

        console.log(dataReturened);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Channel',
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

console.log of dataReturned:

```
Array(3) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […] ]
​0: Array [ "Task", "Views" ]
​1: Array [ "Channel A", 2854170 ]
​2: Array [ "CHannel B", 240222 ]
​length: 3
​<prototype>: Array []
```

Could anyone please tell me, what I am doing wrong here?

**THANK YOU**

Comment: When I tested your script using your sample values, no error occurs. I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for this. So, for example, when your sample values are directly used like `const vodPiechart = _ => [["Task", "Views"], ["Channel A", 2854170], ["CHannel B", 240222]];` instead of your current `vodPiechart`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Can you share the sheet and the steps you used reproduce it?

Comment: @Tanaike If i use const voiPiechart. It was coming blank (empty html page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something about the data is incorrect.

the error message you received is thrown when column headings do not exist in the data.
or the value of the column heading is not a string.

> Uncaught Error: Unknown type of column header: 1

in this case, the number `1` is trying to be used as a column heading.

see following example, the following error will be thrown.

> Uncaught Error: Unknown type of column header: 2854170

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Channel A", 2854170],
    ["Channel B", 240222],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Channel',
    is3D: true,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

---

the `arrayToDataTable` method has a second, boolean argument.
when set to `true`, it will create the data table without column headings,
and use the first row as data.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ["Channel A", 2854170],
  ["Channel B", 240222],
], true);  // <-- first row is data
```

there are really no use for column headings in a pie chart,
because the labels are provided on each row.

try adding the boolean argument for resolution.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Channel A", 2854170],
    ["Channel B", 240222],
  ], true);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Channel',
    is3D: true,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart_3d"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps -- otherwise, please provide a sample of the data --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataReturened));`

Comment: Thank You So Much WhiteHat for your Help.